# Issues with BSEC Library Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-ide

I just want to get the library working in Arduino IDE 1.8.13. However, it always fails to compile.
I have adjusted the platform.txt, however it did not do anything. I have downloaded the library from github (https://github.com/BoschSensortec/BSEC-Arduino-library).
It always comes back the same error when compiling with the ESP32 board.
Where is my mistake?

Here is the debug code:

```
libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/BSEC_Software_Library.a(bsec.cpp.o):(.literal._ZN4Bsec11beginCommonEv+0x4): undefined reference to `bsec_init'
libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/BSEC_Software_Library.a(bsec.cpp.o):(.literal._ZN4Bsec11beginCommonEv+0x8): undefined reference to `bsec_get_version'
libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/BSEC_Software_Library.a(bsec.cpp.o):(.literal._ZN4Bsec18updateSubscriptionEP21bsec_virtual_sensor_thf+0x0): undefined reference to `bsec_update_subscription'
libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/BSEC_Software_Library.a(bsec.cpp.o):(.literal._ZN4Bsec8setStateEPh+0x10): undefined reference to `bsec_set_state'
libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/BSEC_Software_Library.a(bsec.cpp.o):(.literal._ZN4Bsec15readProcessDataEx19bsec_bme_settings_t+0x14): undefined reference to `bsec_do_steps'
libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/BSEC_Software_Library.a(bsec.cpp.o):(.literal._ZN4Bsec3runEx+0x0): undefined reference to `bsec_sensor_control'
libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/BSEC_Software_Library.a(bsec.cpp.o):(.literal._ZN4Bsec3runEx+0x4): undefined reference to `bsec_get_state'
libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/BSEC_Software_Library.a(bsec.cpp.o): In function `Bsec::beginCommon()':
/Users/Service/Documents/Arduino/libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/src/bsec.cpp:476: undefined reference to `bsec_init'
libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/BSEC_Software_Library.a(bsec.cpp.o): In function `Bsec::getVersion()':
/Users/Service/Documents/Arduino/libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/src/bsec.cpp:476: undefined reference to `bsec_get_version'
libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/BSEC_Software_Library.a(bsec.cpp.o): In function `Bsec::updateSubscription(bsec_virtual_sensor_t*, unsigned char, float)':
/Users/Service/Documents/Arduino/libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/src/bsec.cpp:476: undefined reference to `bsec_update_subscription'
libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/BSEC_Software_Library.a(bsec.cpp.o): In function `Bsec::setState(unsigned char*)':
/Users/Service/Documents/Arduino/libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/src/bsec.cpp:476: undefined reference to `bsec_set_state'
libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/BSEC_Software_Library.a(bsec.cpp.o): In function `Bsec::readProcessData(long long, bsec_bme_settings_t)':
/Users/Service/Documents/Arduino/libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/src/bsec.cpp:385: undefined reference to `bsec_do_steps'
libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/BSEC_Software_Library.a(bsec.cpp.o): In function `Bsec::run(long long)':
/Users/Service/Documents/Arduino/libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/src/bsec.cpp:200: undefined reference to `bsec_init'
/Users/Service/Documents/Arduino/libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/src/bsec.cpp:210: undefined reference to `bsec_update_subscription'
/Users/Service/Documents/Arduino/libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/src/bsec.cpp:210: undefined reference to `bsec_sensor_control'
/Users/Service/Documents/Arduino/libraries/BSEC_Software_Library/src/bsec.cpp:246: undefined reference to `bsec_get_state'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1.
```

Thank you

Comment: This is probably not an issue with the BSEC library itself, but in your installation or configuration. How did you install the library? Did you use the library manager in the IDE, or did you install it manually?

Comment: I have tried both. Once I added the zip manually and once I installed it via the library manager from the IDE.

Comment: I see. I just tried it and I get the same error using one of their examples. I did a quick search of their source and did not find a definition for `bsec_init()`.  Assuming I wasn't hasty in my search of their source, there's something else it needs.

Comment: First of all, thanks for testing.
How can we proceed further?

Comment: I haven't had time to dig much further yet, but it seems that there's an external library, `libalgobsec.a`, that it is either not present or it doesn't know where to find it to link to it. Modification of the `platform.txt` file is supposed to help with this. There's a thread [here](https://community.particle.io/t/bsec-sensor-library/41166/7) in which someone has solved the issue in their case. You might be able to glean your solution from that. I will have a look later today when I have more time. Meanwhile, if you construct a solution based upon that, post an answer to your own question. :)

Comment: I'll have a look at the thread. the ```libalgobsec.a``` is located under /src/esp32 , so there seems to be a missing definition for the location somewhere. If you could also take a closer look, that would be very helpful if your time allows it.

Comment: I've been playing with it a bit. I had ESP32 installed in my Arduino IDE 1.8.13 but the structure has been changed. I can't for the life of me find where Arduino stores the `platform.txt` file. I've been using PlatormIO mostly, and those I have found. Just for fun, I copied the basic example from the Arduino bsec lib folder over to PlatformIO and it built right away, so PlatformIO found the external lib without any modification to config files. So the missing element seems to get the Arduino config correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino IDE 1.8.13 will find the library if you make the correct modification to the `platform.txt` file. My file is located here:

```
C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\platform.txt
```

First make sure the general change is in your `platform.txt` file. That is, you have `compiler.libraries.ldflags` defined. My `platform.txt` already had it defined as empty, `compiler.libraries.ldflags=`. If yours is not already defined, then add that line somewhere in your `platform.txt` file.

Next, you want to reference it. You can follow the instructions given for ESP8266. Change the following:

`recipe.c.combine.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.c.elf.cmd}" {compiler.c.elf.flags} {compiler.c.elf.extra_flags} {compiler.libraries.ldflags} -Wl,--start-group {object_files} "{archive_file_path}" {compiler.c.elf.libs} {build.extra_libs} -Wl,--end-group -Wl,-EL -o "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.elf"`

To this:

`recipe.c.combine.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.c.elf.cmd}" {compiler.c.elf.flags} {compiler.c.elf.extra_flags} {compiler.libraries.ldflags} -Wl,--start-group {object_files} "{archive_file_path}" {compiler.c.elf.libs} {compiler.libraries.ldflags} {build.extra_libs} -Wl,--end-group -Wl,-EL -o "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.elf"`

Note the last occurrence of `compiler.libraries.ldflags`. My text shown above does not match the text shown in the github document exactly. I simply added the `compiler.libraries.ldflags` after the `--start-group` directive, which is what the github doc shows.

Once I did this, saved the file, and restarted Arduino, it all compiled and linked successfully.

Comment: Thanks! I had only one error, because of the ```{build.extra_libs}``` flag. After I removed it the IDE is linking all together